# ¿Semirretícula o semiretícula?

Tags: letras, escritura

En el título de mi tesis uso la palabra "*semirretícula*" pero al ser una composición del prefijo "*semi*" y de la palabra "*retícula*", me pregunté si la doble **r** debe emplearse aunque sea una palabra compuesta.

Cabe mencionar que dicha palabra no forma parte de la escritura castellana, es un concepto matemático, pero aún así debería de contar con una forma correcta, según la RAE, de ser escrita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debe escribirse con *r* doble, porque si no, la ortografía no marcaría la cualidad vibrante del consonante.  Así es la regla con toda palabra que comienza con *r-* al ponerle un prefijo terminante en vocal.

Otros ejemplos sería *prerromano*  de *romano* (pero *posromano*), o *infrarrojo* de *rojo*.

*Semirretícula* sería una palabra completamente válida.  La ASALE no puede poner todas las palabras prefijadas en el DLE, y por eso pone solo los prefijos cuando sería evidente el significado (como lo es en *semirretícula*) por saber el significado de la palabra base y el prefijo.

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento a la respuesta de @guifa, [te enlazo](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UuckNoDjlxPbdQoO) y cito la *Ortografía española*:

> Se emplea el dígrafo *rr* en representación del fonema /rr/ en posición intervocálica: *arruga, barrio, susurro, terrible*.
>
> **Advertencia**. En las voces prefijadas o compuestas, debe escribirse *rr* si el fonema /rr/ queda en posición intervocálica, aunque en la palabra simple ese mismo fonema se represente con *r* por ir en posición inicial: *antirrobo* (de *anti-* + *robo*), *infrarrojo* (*infra-* + *rojo*), *prerrománico* (de *pre-* + *románico*), *vicerrector* (de *vice-* + *rector*), *guardarropa* (de *guarda* + *ropa*), *hazmerreír* (de *haz* + *me* + *reír*).

Por tanto sí, se escribe *semirretícula* aunque provenga de *semi-* + *retícula*.